# Populating very long linear layout with custom views, extremely slow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

i'm trying to populate a linear layout with a list of custom views like in the picture:

[image: Layout scheme]
To achieve this i'm inflating the foo.xml in a new View object, then i change the textviews using .setText and then i add the new View to the linear layout.

The problem is: it is extremely slow, even outside the emulator, taking more than 10 seconds to display in my S9.

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

while(a<500){
    Person person = new Person();

    View personData = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person, layout, false);
    layout.addView(personData);
    ((TextView) coinData.findViewById(R.id.textView_text_name)).setText(person.name);

    a=a+1
}
```

EDIT: Thank you guys! I'm gonna try RecyclerView right now

Comment: Why aren't you using [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView)?

Comment: Even Better to go with **[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)**

Comment: Try to use Recyclerview which helps in performance of the screen.

Comment: how many "rows" do you have? really 500? if so, yes, use `RecyclerView`

Comment: that's just fine for it to inflate so long. Also expect it to crash with OutOfMemory exceptions on most part of the devices. Never inflate so so large views, split them into parts and use RecyclerView instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating a list use RecyclerView which is just advanced version of traditional ListView

You can Follow tutorial for Recycler View [Here.](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)